# Ionic iOS build error with google-plus plugin

Tags: ios, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, google-plus-signin

How to resolve the following error? I'm not sure where to start...When trying to build my Ionic project for iOS, I get the following error:

```
$ ionic cordova build ios
....
/Plugins/cordova-plugin-googleplus/GooglePlus.h:2:9: fatal error: 'GoogleSignIn/GoogleSignIn.h' file not found
#import <GoogleSignIn/GoogleSignIn.h>
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

It works great on Android! But I'm not sure what to do about this iOS build error.
My current version of the plugin is: 5.3.0 "Google SignIn"

With the following info:

> cli packages:
>
> ```
> @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
> ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0
> ```
>
> global packages:
>
> ```
> cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
> ```
>
> local packages:
>
> ```
> @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.9
> Cordova Platforms  : android 7.0.0 browser 5.0.3 ios 4.1.1
> Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
> ```
>
> System:
>
> ```
> Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
> ios-deploy        : 1.9.0
> ios-sim           : 5.0.11
> Node              : v8.11.1
> npm               : 6.0.0
> OS                : macOS Sierra
> Xcode             : Xcode 9.2 Build version 9C40b
> ```

---

UPDATE: It does seem like a dependency error in xcode.
I am trying to manually add the GoogleSignin SDK using the instructions here: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sdk/

---

#### Resolved:

In xcode, I dragged and dropped the following 3 files (GoogleSignIn.bundle, GoogleSignIn.framework, GoogleSignInDependencies.framework) from the Google Sign-In SDK - making sure to check the “Copy items into destination group’s folder (if needed)” option.

Now when I build, the dependency to SignIn is resolved.

Comment: mine it worked fine. do you still have this problem?

Comment: its better to update your Xcode to latest version. my Xcode version is  **`Xcode 9.3 Build version 9E145`**. and try to rebuild it again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Went to: https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/getting-started

Downloaded `Google+ iOS SDK` and added `GoogleOpenSource.framework` manually.

Comment: Hi Gurbela, thanks for the info. I'm not very familiar with xcode, I've tried finding more information but still yet to find exactly what I need to do. Following instructions (link below), how do I add the GoogleSigning framework to the xcode project? Do I need to copy the files to the same folder, do i need to drag/drop, do i need to "Add Files" from xcode? thx for the help https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sdk/